# Incorrect reading of input file c++

Tags: c++

I want to read from a file.txt that looks like this:

process_id   run_time  arrival_time

T1             23         0

T2             75         5

then I will save in arrays

My problem is: the 1st iteration outputs: T 1 2 and that's incorrect

any help please? thanks

```
while (!ManageFile.eof()) 
{


    ManageFile>>rubbish; //read the word process_id
    ManageFile>>rubbish; //read the word run_time
    ManageFile>>rubbish; //read the word arrival_time

    while (true) 
    {
    ManageFile>>process_id[i];
    cout << process_id[i]<<endl;
    ManageFile>>run_time[i];
    cout << run_time[i]<<endl;
    ManageFile>>arrival_time[i];
    cout << arrival_time[i]<<endl;
    i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please, Please, search StackOverflow for "c++ read file array" before continuing.  There are too many similar questions to yours, but since they are not *exactly* duplicate, I can't close this as duplicate.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Why do you have an infinite loop that never exits?

Comment: it loops till the end of the lines of the file

Comment: @MaramAlaa Not true. Inner while is going to loop infinitely. Btw. what is type of `process_id` ? You are almost sure read only one `byte/char/...`

Comment: @MaramAlaa `while(true)` loops until a flow control statement pulls execution out of its scope (like `break`) or the program otherwise terminates.  With that in mind, `eof` should rarely be a loop control for input anyway, you probably want to use `while (ManageFile>>process_id[i])` as your second loop and take out the first.